# Dynamically add textareas client-side to a form in lift

Tags: scala, lift

I've got a form based on the sample in http://simply.liftweb.net/index-4.2.html#toc-Section-4.2 and I was wondering if there's a way of having a button on the page that would add a textarea each time it's clicked, and then in the lift code get that as an array of strings.

What I'm picturing is something like this:

```
<form class="lift:OnSubmit?form=post">
  Name: <input name="name"><br>
  Age: <input name="age" value="0"><br>
<span id="somecomments"></span>
<input type="button" onclick="$('#somecomments').append($('<textarea cols=80 rows=10 name=comments>'))" value="Add Comment"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

//in scala:
object OnSubmit {
  def render = {
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
    var comments = List("")​
    def process() {
        S.notice("Name: "+name)
        S.notice("Age: "+age)
        S.notice(comments)
        S.redirectTo("/")
      }
    }​
    "name=name" #> SHtml.onSubmit(name = _) &
    "name=age" #> SHtml.onSubmit(s => asInt(s).foreach(age = _)) &
    "name=comments" #> SHtml.onSubmit(comments = _) &
    "type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(process)
  }
}
```

But I get the compile error that the comments field is a String so I can't assign it to a List with "name=comments" #> SHtml.onSubmit(comments = _)

What's the best way to make this code work?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?  I'm looking for "the right way" do do this same thing and am struggling to figure out a non-hacky Lift-like way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

for prepending:

```
"name=comments" #> SHtml.onSubmit(comments ::= _)
```

for appending:

```
"name=comments" #> SHtml.onSubmit(comments :+= _)
```

Comment: That works if I change my HTML to have multiple textareas with the name "comments", but it doesn't work for the fields that are dynamically added by the javascript. I want to be able to hit the button multiple times and have all those new textareas added

Answer (score 0):

Here I describe how you can add any number of fields (I have a textarea and a "related" numeric field.

You add them using jQuery and then Lift gets all the data as a json object.

[Dynamically adding fields to a Lift application](http://goo.gl/Mu1eu)